# Sort product collection on attribute value instead of id

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, catalog, filter

On Magento 1.9.x.x. I want to get the product with the lowest value in a given category. I use the following code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('page_number')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addFieldToFilter('category_id',$category->getId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('page_number',array('notnull' => true))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
    ->addAttributeToSort('page_number', 'ASC')
    ->getFirstItem();
```

The page_number is an multi-select with integers as key and value. For example: Page 1 can have ID 512 and page 2 can have 412 as ID. So sorting on the ID's won’t work, I need to sort on the actual values.

Is it possible to do this directly? I don’t want to get all products and loop trough them because of performance.